# Domain for the Composition of Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Question:I want to find the Domain of $f \circ f \circ f (x)$ given $f(x)=\sqrt{2-x}$

Attempt at solution: Domain of $f \circ f\circ f$ is $x \le-2 $ 
$\cap$ Domain of $f\circ f$ is $x\ge-2$ 
$\cap$ Domain of $f$ is $x\le2$

Whereas the final domain in the program gives me $[-2,2]$ which I definitely can't obtain from the above intersection.

So please tell me where I went wrong and what I am supposed to do. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f \circ f \circ f (x)$ given $f(x)=\sqrt{2-x}$

Therefore $$f \circ f \circ f (x) = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-x}}}$$

So we have 3 conditions 
$$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-x}}  \le 2.....(i)$$ and
$$\sqrt{2-x} \le 2.....(ii)$$ and
$$x \le 2.....(iii)$$

From (i) and (ii) we get,
$$-2 \le \sqrt{2-x} \le 2.....(iv) $$
From (iii) and (iv) we get, $$-2 \le x \le 2$$

Required domain = $[-2,2]$

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this for me.!!

Comment: You're always welcome!